# How and what to set a pending Intent ID to

Tags: java, android, android-pendingintent

My app has the ability to allow users to set an appointment. This also includes an alarm that is triggered through a pending intent on the set specified date of the appointment. When the set date arrives, a toast message displays that there appointment is today.

The users also have the ability to edit their appointment, this includes being able to turn the alarm on and off (through the use of a toggle button) I want to be able to cancel the pending intent if they turn the alarm off. This obviously means I need to rely on a unique ID.

Here's my main question:

**What is the best way to set the ID? I have no real 'unique' values I can set, I have seen people set 'current times' to the ID then add this as an EXTRA but what if I have two pending intent alarms with the exact same time?**

When I create a new appointment this auto increments the ID and will literally set a pending intent alarm that is not 'bound' to this user.

Here is my current pending intent code:

```
AlarmManager dateSet = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DateAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    dateSet.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setDate.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Alarm class:

```
package com.example.flybase2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DateAlarm extends Activity {

Context context;
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    Toast newToast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    newToast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL, 0, 0);
     newToast.makeText(context, "Appointment is today", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number and use it as your unique id.  Store that number in SharePreferences or a sqlite database.  That also seeds the ability to persist your alarms between device reboots.

Or System.currentTimeMillis() really ought to give you what you need.  It would be very rare for you to get 2 IDs of exactly the same millis.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Im currently thinking of adding an extra column to my appointments database with the column name 'alarm' then I could add the random generated number from this and pass the value within the ID. Can you see any issues with this?

Comment: If you already have a database use the "id" for the row ;)  It's auto-incrementing and you'll never have it repeat.  Sometimes the simplest answer is the best answer.  Don't forget upvotes/checkmarks if my answer helped ;)